# BeforeStep Karate

Tags: ui-automation, karate, browser-automation

I'm working with iFramed web(micro frontend), the iFrame wraps the entire body(element inside it), and I need to switch iFrame every time the page loads.

```
Given driver siteUrl
And call read('classpath:web/pages/login/login.feature@login_with_email') args
* def args = {main_menu: fleet-management, submenu: Truk}
And call read('classpath:web/internal/pages/dashboard/dashboard.feature@open_page') args
# LOAD NEW PAGE
* waitFor(iFrameId).switchFrame()
And click(pageA.elementA)
# LOAD NEW PAGE
* waitFor(iFrameId).switchFrame()
And click(PageB.elementB)
```

Since `switchFrame` will be used frequently, **beforeStep** will be a great solution.
I've done research :

- https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/970

> Hook.java

```
    @Override
    public boolean beforeStep(Step step, ScenarioRuntime sr)
    {
        Runner.runFeature("classpath:utils/helper.feature@switch_frame", null, false);
    }
```

> helper.feature

```
Feature: Test Feature For Switch Frame
  @switch_frame
  Scenario: Switching focus to iFrame
    * waitFor(iFrameId).switchFrame()
```

but right now I'm stuck, *helper.feature* called from *hook.java* unable to use any keywords(waitFor, switchFrame) and unable to get global variable set from *karate-config.js*.

Please help, Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I think this is over-engineering and `Runner.runFeature()` is not designed to do this.

How about you combine the frame switching and click into a single function:

```
* def frameClick = function(frame, locator){ waitFor(frame).switchFrame(); click(locator) }
```

Now you can do:

```
* frameClick(iFrameId, pageA.elementA)
```

You can even be smarter and set the `frameId` one-time:

```
* frameClick(pageA.elementA)
```